# Org-mode find tasks with no deadlines, transitively

Tags: org-mode

I'm using sparse trees (not in agenda view, but in "normal" tree view) to help me get a clear picture of what I have to do, at a glance.

I would like to create a sparse tree that shows all the tasks that have no deadlines, and whose parents also have no deadlines.

Is that possible with a search query? If not, how can I do it?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case someone else is interested, I found out a way to do it.

The "trick" is to make `DEADLINE` an inherited property. While subtasks with only inherited deadlines will still not show up in the agenda (for those deadlines), search criteria involving deadlines will apply to them anyway.

To make `DEADLINE` an inherited property, use:

```el
(setq org-use-property-inheritance (quote ("DEADLINE")))
```

Then find tasks without a deadline with:

```
C-c / m -DEADLINE={.}
```

Or the full command:

```el
(org-match-sparse-tree nil "-DEADLINE={.}")
```

Sources:

- The following thread gave me the way to make DEADLINE inherited: http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.orgmode/48932
- The org-mode manual explains how search for tasks with not scheduled date: http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/advanced-searching.html#sec-7

Comment: Ok, since nobody else has commented in over a year, I'm accepting my answer.